# Unable to remove &#13; string from text I am extracting from html

Tags: string, python-2.7, unicode, replace

I am trying to extract the main article from a web page. I can accomplish the main text extraction using Python's readability module. However the text I get back often contains several &#13 strings (there is a ; at the end of this string but this editor won't allow the full string to be entered (strange!)). I have tried using the python replace function, I have also tried using regular expression's replace function, I have also tried using the unicode encode and decode functions. None of these approaches have worked. For the replace and Regular Expression approaches I just get back my original text with the &#13 strings still present and with the unicode encode decode approach I get back the error message:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 2099: ordinal not in range(128)

Here is the code I am using that takes the initial URL and using readability extracts the main article. I have left in all my commented out code that corresponds to the different approaches I have tried to remove the  string. It appears as though &#13 is interpreted to be u'\xa9'.

```
from readability.readability import Document

def find_main_article_text_2():
    #url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/news/questcor-pharmaceuticals-closes-transaction-acquire-130000695.html'
    url = "http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/industry/news/latestnews/*http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/cbsm/SIG=11iiumket/*http://www.marketwatch.com/News/Story/Story.aspx?guid=4D9D3170-CE63-4570-B95B-9B16ABD0391C&siteid=yhoof2"
    html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    readable_article = Document(html).summary()
    readable_title = Document(html).short_title()
    #readable_article.replace("u'\xa9'"," ")
    #print re.sub("&#13;",'',readable_article)
    #unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', readable_article).encode('ascii','ignore')
    print readable_article
    #print readable_article.decode('latin9').encode('utf8'),
    print "There are " ,readable_article.count("&#13;"),"&#13;'s"

    #print readable_article.encode( sys.stdout.encoding , '' )


    #sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
    #sents = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(readable_article)
    #new_sents = []
    #for sent in sents:
    #    unicode_sent = sent.decode('utf-8')
    #    s1 = unicode_sent.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
    #s2 = s1.replace("\n","")
    #    new_sents.append(s1)
    #print new_sents
    # u'\xa9'
```

I have a URL that I have been testing the code with included inside the def. If anybody has any ideas on how to remove this &#13 I would appreciate the help. Thanks, George